# ng-pattern not working for dynamically added input tag in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a input tag in a variable with `ng-pattern` when I inserted it into a div its `ng-pattern` is not working

**style:**

```
.from_fields {
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
    background: transparent;
}
.from_fields.ng-invalid {
    color: white;
    background: red;
}
```

**Script**

```
$scope.input='<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" class="from_fields">';
angular.element(document.getElementById('test')).html($scope.input);
```

can someone help??

Comment: try this <input type="text" ng-model="numberfield" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{1,7}$/" class="from_fields"> Use ng-model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you are trying to enter needs to be compiled for angular to have it in its watch list and have any ng attributes evaluated.

Right now ng-pattern is a regular custom data attribute with no meaning to angular

If you dont want to bind in an angular controller just remove the ng-

leaving

```
'<input type="text" pattern="^[0-9]{1,7}$" class="from_fields">';
```

**note that the pattern attribute does not need slashes**

otherwise you will have to import in your controller the $compile service

and compile the string given a $scope variable

```
var input = '<input type="text" ng-pattern="^[0-9]{1,7}$" class="from_fields">';
var compiled_input = $compile(input)($scope)
```

and the append it to the document

```
angular.element(<selector>).append(input);
```